# Branch Prediction and CPI

Tags: performance, branch, cpu-architecture, prediction

This is a problem from an exam I took recently and I'm just curious to know if I was on the right track with my answer.

If I remember correctly it was:  Consider a machine that resolves all branches in the ID stage of the datapath.  There are 14% branches and 86% other instructions.  The branch prediction is incorrect 45% of the time.  Ignore all other possible hazards.  What is the CPI of this machine?

Here's what I did (assuming base CPI of 1):  (.86)(1) + (.14)((.55)(1)+(.45)(1+1))) = 1.063

Did I get the answer correct, or did I miss something about that problem?

Comment: That looks correct to me. With decode as the second stage of a scalar pipeline, only one canceled instruction will be fetched on a misprediction before the correct direction is fetched, adding one cycle to the cost of a branch on a misprediction.

Comment: Phew.  Thanks for reassuring me.